# how do I send the text to another line, I have a picture then text. if texts are too long, I want the text to be under the first text line

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit:I see I provided wrong fiddle, sorry people. Here;s the one with fixed ones.
sorry if the title is too long. I'll narrate again here. 
I have a table, and inside that table each cell has a picture and texts. if the texts are too long, the text goes under the picture. The text should go under the first line of that text. If this is not possible, as an alternate I would like to do

```
"white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;" if the text goes over 60.
```

Here;s my code with not enough texts to mess things up; https://jsfiddle.net/crs8yenu/164/

```
<h4 id="line">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 15px; text-decoration:none;"> <img src="{{post.image}}" height="70" width="85"/><span id="title-font">
          aaaaaaaa</span></a>
        <span style="margin-left: 15px;" class="domain">({{ post.domain }})</span>
        <span class="discuss" style="color:red;"><a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">enter</a></span>

      </h4>
```

Here;s with enough texts to mess things up https://jsfiddle.net/crs8yenu/166/

```
<h4 id="line">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 15px; text-decoration:none;"> <img src="{{post.image}}" height="70" width="85"/><span id="title-font">
          aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></a>
        <span style="margin-left: 15px;" class="domain">({{ post.domain }})</span>
        <span class="discuss" style="color:red;"><a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">enter</a></span>

      </h4>
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I did you can check out my fiddle, I showed my problem and what I want to solve to

Comment: oh I see I pasted wrong fiddle sorry

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu fixed the question

Comment: @BrianD fixed the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.
I added a single line of CSS to target that link, told it to display as an inline block (so I could set its width) and then gave it a max-width property to limit the width.

```
h4#line a:first-of-type{
    max-width:250px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crs8yenu/167/

Also possible this is what you're looking for - Instead of displaying that first link as an `inline-block`, I set the span within the link (containing your title text) to display as an `inline-block` so it would sit nicely next to your image. Next I set it to `vertical-align: top` so that it would align with the top of the image instead of the bottom (gives your wrapping text somewhere to wrap to), and I gave it a `max-width` (to prevent it from expanding infinitely to the right) and a `max-height` equal to the explicit height you set in your image to ensure that it wouldn't end up taller than the image.

```
#title-font {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 70px;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crs8yenu/169/